# How to add range search criteria to API call?

Tags: python, api

I want to ask the customer how many calories per meal, then search using that criteria. I am unsure how to integrate the input into the range search.

```py
import requests

def recipe_search(ingredient):
    recipes_appid = '0f89098e'
    recipes_appkey = '80a8b7c8361daa22182bc3b3eb9f277e'
    url = 'https://api.edamam.com/search?q={}&app_id={}&app_key={}&calories={}'.format(ingredient, recipes_appid,
                                                                                       recipes_appkey, calories)
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()

    return (data['hits'])

def run():
    ingredient = input('What ingredient is used by date first?')
    calories = input('Do you have a desired estimated calorie intake per meal?')

    results = recipe_search(ingredient) and recipe_search(calories_band)


run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a second parameter to `recipe_search` with a default value so you're not mandatory to give it to the method

```
def recipe_search(ingredient, calories=500):
    recipes_appid = '0f89098e'
    recipes_appkey = '80a8b7c8361daa22182bc3b3eb9f277e'
    url = 'https://...={}'.format(ingredient, recipes_appid, recipes_appkey, calories)
```

Then call with `results = recipe_search(ingredient, calories_band)`

---

Simplifying a bit the bound check, you can have

```
def run():
    ingredient = input('What ingredient is used by date first?')
    calories = input('Do you have a desired estimated calorie intake per meal?') or 200
    lower_bound = 100
    upper_bound = 300
    calories = min(max(int(calories), lower_bound), upper_bound)
    results = recipe_search(ingredient, calories)
    for result in results:
        recipe = result['recipe']
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks - super clear and simple. Only Q would be that it returns error:
TypeError: recipe_search() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

How can you search with two positional arguments?

Comment: @CTheFridge did you update the recipe_search method ? As i explain at the beginning of my code ?

Comment: perfect - thank you

Comment: perfect - thank you

Comment: perfect - thank you